# Boolean Function in pandas df column - object orientation - ambiguous truth value of a series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, object, boolean

I need some help creating a dataframe column containing a boolean function.  I would like to receive a value of True or False based on a condition concerning other df column data .

dataframe:

```
            date    C   A
0   2020-02-04  3284.75 3284.75
1   2020-02-05  3322.25 3303.50
2   2020-02-06  3333.25 3327.75
3   2020-02-07  3315.50 3324.38
4   2020-02-10  3340.25 3327.88
5   2020-02-11  3345.50 3342.88
6   2020-02-12  3367.00 3356.25
7   2020-02-13  3363.50 3365.25
8   2020-02-14  3368.25 3365.88
```

Here is the function:

```
def func(C, A):
    for i in range(3):
        if C.shift(i) >= A.shift(i):
            j + 1
    if j == 3:
        val = True
    else:
        val = False
    return val
```

Here I am calling the function:

```
    data['Func'] = data.apply(func(data['C'], data['A']), axis=1)
```

The error I am getting with this example is

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

The most frequent error I receive trying to get this to work is

```
TypeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object is not callable
```

and

```
AttributeError: ("'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'shift'",
```

At this point I am not sure what elements are working or not working.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The function is attempting to ascertain when there is a series of three consecutive rows where the "C" value is greater than the "A" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Row-wise `.apply` is like a glorified `for-loop`, which means `C` and `A` in your function are each equal to a single value, not a series. Therefore `shift` will not work.
- You can try [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)
- The expected output is not entirely clear, so hopefully this will get you on the right track.

```py
import numpy as np

df['Func'] = np.where((df.C.shift(0) >= df.A.shift(0)) & (df.C.shift(1) >= df.A.shift(1)) & (df.C.shift(2) >= df.A.shift(2)), True, False)

display(df)

       C        A   Func
 3284.75  3284.75  False
 3322.25  3303.50  False
 3333.25  3327.75   True
 3315.50  3324.38  False
 3340.25  3327.88  False
 3345.50  3342.88  False
 3367.00  3356.25   True
 3363.50  3365.25  False
 3368.25  3365.88  False
```

### Explanation

- For each row, each condition must be `True` for `Func` to be `True`

#### `shift(0)`

```py
df.C.shift(0) >= df.A.shift(0)

date
2020-02-04     True
2020-02-05     True
2020-02-06     True
2020-02-07    False
2020-02-10     True
2020-02-11     True
2020-02-12     True
2020-02-13    False
2020-02-14     True
```

#### `shift(1)`

```py
df.C.shift(1) >= df.A.shift(1)

date
2020-02-04    False
2020-02-05     True
2020-02-06     True
2020-02-07     True
2020-02-10    False
2020-02-11     True
2020-02-12     True
2020-02-13     True
2020-02-14    False
```

#### `shift(2)`

```py
df.C.shift(2) >= df.A.shift(2)

date
2020-02-04    False
2020-02-05    False
2020-02-06     True
2020-02-07     True
2020-02-10     True
2020-02-11    False
2020-02-12     True
2020-02-13     True
2020-02-14     True
```

Comment: Thank you Trenton McKinney for this thorough answer.  This code indeed works.  Would say that this approach is "vectorized?"  I am researching this topic now.  The real purpose of this function has more than a three row look back and will be performed over large data sets so I would like to refine this computation to be performed as efficiently as possible.  Possibly this is a question all its own.  Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: @Ludlow_Luddite Yes, my understanding is this type of Boolean slicing is vectorized. Glad it works.  `.apply` is like an efficient `for-loop`.